# jQuery ui Selectable() need ctrl+click to select but I want draggable+ multi click to select

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using `selectable()` of jQuery-ui, It working perfect for me while clicking ctrl+click and dragging also.

But I want to change the Ctrl+click to only single click, and this click also select my squares row.

Here is an example, where single click select the squares. I need this.
http://www.social-contests.com/check-image/

Thanks you so much...

```js
$cover.selectable({
        stop: function () {
            var total = $('.square').size();
            var selected = $('.square.ui-selected').size();
            var percent = Math.round(selected * 100 / total);
            var alert = $('#score').find('.alert').addClass('hide');
            if (percent <= 20) {
                $('#score').find('.alert-success').removeClass('hide');
            } else {
                $('#score').find('.alert-error').removeClass('hide');
            }
            $("#score").find('span.score-value').html(percent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't easy :) But I think I found solution. I had to dig into the source code, and I found that we can **simulate** that we press `ctrlKey`. The solution actually is very easy:

```
event.originalEvent.ctrlKey = true;
```

**Note** that if you set `true` like this:

```
event.ctrlKey = true;
```

it will not give effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/awguykk4/